# Using a holiday calendar in kdb?

Tags: kdb

has anyone ever implemented a holiday calendar in kdb?

it's pretty easy to exclude weekends or to create a function to get nextweekday or previous weekday, but what if you want to also take into account public holidays / bank holidays?

What have people done in order to account for this?

A rudimentary way is to create a file with known bank holidays across LDN & NY let's say - but is there a more automated way?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [holiday.q](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/holiday.q) on Github.  Note that NYSE rules change from time to time so you may need to make some adjustments to bring that code up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Most places will have purchased some form of calendar data product (.e.g Copp Clark). From that you'd build a suite of functions for getPrevBizDay etc, and you'd do it for all regions. It will also have future holidays.

Alternatively I'm sure there are some open source holiday data downloads you could scrape from the web and from them you could manually put together a table (perhaps it would be an annual once-off process to update it for the next year).